# Still having ddl redirect issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am still having issues. I think what I am trying to do is simple. I have a viewbag droplist - which is working fine. I just want to redirect on selection it redirect just like: `@Html.ActionLink("Branch", "Employees", new { Branch = item.Branch })`  | (but with the selection from the droplist) Should this be difficult?

```
@Html.DropDownList("Branches", ViewBag.Branches as SelectList, "Select a Branch", new { @id = "ddlBranch" })

<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#ddlBranch").on("change", function () {
            var deptId = $(this).val();
            var routeVal = { Id: deptId };
            var url = '@Url.Action("Department", "Home")';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: routeVal
            }).done(function (result) {
                window.location.href = result.newUrl;
            })
        })

    })
</script>
```

Comment: "Having issues" isn't a meaningful description of the problem.  In what way does this fail?  Are there any errors?  Unexpected behavior?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, is there any output on the browser console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  What specifically happens?

Comment: It does nothing at all on selection of the Drop List. It does not appear the AJAX request is made.

Comment: So this `change` event is never invoked in the first place?  Or does it get invoked but fail before the AJAX request is made?  Please be specific.  If it's not even being invoked, what is the resulting client-side HTML for the `<select>` element?  Are there other elements with the same `id`?  Is jQuery loaded at all?

Comment: OK. Here is where I am at:

This returns the value of the DropList:

@Html.DropDownList("Branch", ViewBag.Branches as SelectList, "Select a Branch")
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$( "#Branch").change(function() {
 alert($(this).val());
});


So now I just need to redirect to: @Html.ActionLink("Branch", "Employees", new { Branch = item.Branch }) but Item.Branch would be $(this).val(). Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

From a comment on the question above:

> So now I just need to redirect to: `@Html.ActionLink("Branch", "Employees", new { Branch = item.Branch })` but `Item.Branch` would be `$(this).val()`. Can this be done?

There may be a more elegant way, but an approach I've always taken is something like this:

```
let url = '@Html.ActionLink("Branch", "Employees", new { Branch = "REPLACEME" })';
url = url.replace('REPLACEME', $(this).val());
window.location.href = url;
```

On the client-side this turns into something like:

```
let url = '/Brand/Employees?Branch=REPLACEME';
url = url.replace('REPLACEME', encodeURIComponent($(this).val()));
window.location.href = url;
```

Which would look silly to anybody examining only the client-side code, I'm sure.  But since the `Branch` parameter *might* be in the query string or *might* be in the route, and since it's the ASP.NET MVC Framework's responsibility to manage that, generating the URL and putting the client-side value *into* the URL are two separate responsibilities here.

So we use the server-side code to generate the URL with a placeholder (can be any string, `"REPLACEME"` was an arbitrary choice) and then use the client-side code to dynamically replace that placeholder with the desired value.

This essentially replaces whatever you're trying to do with AJAX in the original question.  Unless you need to invoke a server-side operation to get a result not known to the client-side code in order to build the URL, you can just omit the AJAX entirely and build the URL directly.